# Can't find desktop shortcuts

Tags: 14.04

I updated Ubuntu to 14.04 about two weeks ago. In this last week or so I have noticed I can't find any of my desktop shortcuts. None of them are there. I can go to Desktop in Files and they will all be there, they just don't appear on my desktop until I go to the Desktop file in Files. Does anyone know how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean? If you mean that nothing shows up on your desktop,  no icons or anything, just the background,  then you should try my fix: install `gnome-tweak-tool` and click around until you find a toggle for icons on the desktop. It fixed my problem immediately (even though it took me hours to figure out this solution).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i didn't understand your question.
Anyway, did you see the standard shortcuts tab on Settings ?

They are on

> System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts